# Ionic 3: buttons are not clickable and inputs can't be edited on browser

Tags: ionic3

I can't add inputs on browser and also clicking button doesn't execute sign() in ts file.

```
 <ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating >Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button block (click)="sign()">Sign In</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you please add html content from <ion-content> tag?

Comment: please update question

Comment: I added html content from <ion-content> .Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please check the console and share the error here

Comment: No error is displayed in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Set an attribute disabled="false" explicitly on ion-item element.

Details:

If you look into the code of ion-input near standard input tag there is a

This div usually intersects touchstart, touchend, mousedown, and mouseup events for whatever reasons. ([link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/master/src/components/input/input.ts#L134))

But the most important point is that when the correspondent input is disabled, this div does not react on any events using pointer-events: none rule ([link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/master/src/components/input/input.scss#L100))

It seems that ion-input sets the disabled attribute to true by default and reassigns it after the next change detection cycle. So explicitly setting the disabled="false" might help ionic to use a correct default value.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="sign()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <button ion-button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: @Janaka can you please post your sign() function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-input placeholder="Username" [value]="uname" [(ngModel)]="uname"  type="text"  ></ion-input>



<ion-input placeholder="Password"  [value]="pass" [(ngModel)]="pass"  type="password"   ></ion-input>

<button  ion-button large full  (click)="sign()">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: I created new ionic project with same code. It works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem. Try to put ion-item outside the ion-list (remove the ion-list). I don't know why but it's working for me. (Ionic 4)

```
//<ion-list></ion-list>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```